# Wordpress wp_nav_menu breaking link layout only when using custom menus

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu

I hope there is a simple css fix for that. The problem is quite simple, I'm making a custom wordpress theme and I'm using some custom menus, code is working fine, but I've made an inline menu css style with separators (made from border-left: 1px etc, see the css.) and there is a display bug.

The menu is showing fine when it's the default wordpress menu (list of wordpress pages), but when I insert custom links using the menu editor in wordpress admin pannel, the separators are pushed by some kind of space!

See the [jsFiddle illustrating the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/gableroux/DkLbr/) for the generated html

functions.php

```
register_nav_menus(
    array( 'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' ), 'footer-menu' => __( 'Footer Menu' ))
);
```

footer.php

```
<div id="last-footer">
<div id="last-footer-container" class="container_12">
    <div id="last-footer-menu" class="grid_12" align="center">
        <?php 
            wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'footer-menu' ) );
        ?>  
    </div>  
    <div class="clear"></div>
          <!-- other stuff here (widgets) -->
</div><!-- #last-footer-container end -->
```

style.css (generated with lesscss :P)

```
#last-footer {
  background:#222;
  color:white;
}
#last-footer-container {
  padding-bottom:10px;
  padding-top:10px;
}
#last-footer-container a { color:#a62e0d; }
#last-footer-container a:hover {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#602000;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px black;
}
#last-footer-container span { float:left; }

#last-footer-menu ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#last-footer-menu ul li {
  border-left:1px solid #121212;
  border-right:1px solid #323232;
  display:inline;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
  margin:0;
}
#last-footer-menu ul li:first-child { border-left:none; }
#last-footer-menu ul li:last-child { border-right:none; }
```

Comment: Note: removing endlines between the `<li>` tags will fix the display issue, but because the html is generated by wordpress, this is not a valuable fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I'd have a look at this and it ended up driving me nuts too.  The issue relates to the `display: inline` on the `#last-footer-menu ul li` selector.

I ended up just floating each of those links and then creating a centered nav menu using this ye olde technique - [Horizontally centering an unordered list](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/beautiful-css-centered-menus-no-hacks-full-cross-browser-support)

Here's the JS Fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/rabmcnab/zvCsC/1/

I'd like to see some cleaner and meaner solution to this, we'll see if anyone weighs in with an alternative that used fewer CSS changes to achieve.

Comment: This is indeed a working solution, but I'll wait until someone find an alternative as you say or else I'll mark your answer as the solution ;). Thanks alot!

Comment: No problem and you are quite right!  I want to see a better solution myself, but glad to at least have been able to help offer a working one for now.

Comment: I spent some time again to achieve this with css only, but it seems the only way is to float things as you did so thanks again because it works very well :).